# space between content and fixed bottom navigation

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a home page with Bootstrap 4 which contains only a navigation bar with fixed-bottom style and a carousel above it.

The looks on desktop/tablet view is okay, but the problem is on **mobile views.**

On mobile views, there's a **white space** between the carousel and the navigation that i want to get rid of. How can i achieve this?

I have tried this,  but it did not work.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {body {overflow: hidden;}
```

Here's my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wb13o8nv/13/

Kindly need your help on this matter, thank you.

Comment: is there only slider and navbar on home page ?

Comment: you can give full height to slider

Comment: yes, there's only a navbar and slider on the home page.

Comment: Mobile height is more that of the images. So you want  the images cover the whole viewport height irrespective of the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution For this Question is to use the images in the slide show as the `background image` for each of the `carousel-item`.

**CSS**

```
.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.sliderCarousel {
  width: 100%;
}
.sliderCarousel .carousel-item {
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 4 Website Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-bottom">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#collapsibleNavbar"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div
      id="carouselExampleIndicators"
      class="carousel slide sliderCarousel"
      data-ride="carousel"
    >
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li
          data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-slide-to="0"
          class="active"
        ></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner h-100">
        <div
          class="carousel-item h-100 active"
          style="background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1551706646-9c816bfbff8c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80')"
        ></div>
        <div
          class="carousel-item h-100"
          style="background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1551706646-9c816bfbff8c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80')"
        ></div>
        <div
          class="carousel-item h-100"
          style="background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1551706646-9c816bfbff8c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80')"
        ></div>
      </div>
      <a
        class="carousel-control-prev"
        href="#carouselExampleIndicators"
        role="button"
        data-slide="prev"
      >
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a
        class="carousel-control-next"
        href="#carouselExampleIndicators"
        role="button"
        data-slide="next"
      >
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde
          deserunt dolores cum optio sed exercitationem dolore rerum
          consectetur, voluptatibus nemo molestias laudantium ea, soluta ab iste
          voluptates veritatis quos dignissimos?
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var setCarouselHeight = function() {
    $(".sliderCarousel").height(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
  };
  setCarouselHeight();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    setCarouselHeight();
  });
});
```

Here I am using js to calculate the height of the viewport and set the height of the carousel.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var setCarouselHeight = function() {
    $(".sliderCarousel").height(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
  };
  setCarouselHeight();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    setCarouselHeight();
  });
});
```

```css
.no-gutters {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
.sliderCarousel {
  width: 100%;
}
.sliderCarousel .carousel-item {
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 4 Website Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-bottom">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#collapsibleNavbar"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div
      id="carouselExampleIndicators"
      class="carousel slide sliderCarousel"
      data-ride="carousel"
    >
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li
          data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"
          data-slide-to="0"
          class="active"
        ></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner h-100">
        <div
          class="carousel-item h-100 active"
          style="background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1551706646-9c816bfbff8c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80')"
        ></div>
        <div
          class="carousel-item h-100"
          style="background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1551706646-9c816bfbff8c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80')"
        ></div>
        <div
          class="carousel-item h-100"
          style="background-image:url('https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1551706646-9c816bfbff8c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80')"
        ></div>
      </div>
      <a
        class="carousel-control-prev"
        href="#carouselExampleIndicators"
        role="button"
        data-slide="prev"
      >
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a
        class="carousel-control-next"
        href="#carouselExampleIndicators"
        role="button"
        data-slide="next"
      >
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde
          deserunt dolores cum optio sed exercitationem dolore rerum
          consectetur, voluptatibus nemo molestias laudantium ea, soluta ab iste
          voluptates veritatis quos dignissimos?
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Working Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/43q56djs/4/)

Comment: Thank you Chandra, this is a bit advance for me but i get the idea. I will implement it later or i can simply add the padding to my nav so it will fill the mobile viewport. Thank you very much.

Comment: @SholihinIwanSetiawan, Cool Happy Coding :D

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the whole navigation and carousel in a division with a `position-relative` class.
And give your nav a `position-absolute` class.

https://jsfiddle.net/y1fwv04d/

Comment: I figured he would want to keep the nav visible during desktop, which is why I didn't suggest this.

Comment: Nav is visible in desktop views.

Comment: If too wide it gets pushed below viewport with your solution. :)

Comment: Thank You Zaenab, yes i want to keep my nav visible on mobile. Your solution of adding positon is still not answering my problem as there's a white space below the navbar on mobile view.

Comment: ohh, sorry!! :D

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was flawed. This answer is better, but your nav will not show in viewport in some cases. What you are requesting is a full-page view no matter what dimensions the viewport. I wish you luck, and suggest you just put the nav at the top like everyone else: https://jsfiddle.net/asd3m98o/
+1 for Zoey for a semantic layout.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<div class="min-vh-100 overflow-hidden">
      Carousel here
      <img class="d-block h-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/flagged/photo-1551706646-9c816bfbff8c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1567&q=80" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <footer class="sticky-bottom">Your nav here</footer>
```

Sorry I can't write much complete code, I am writing this from my phone. But I hope this is what you are looking for.